# gRPC serialization behavior for local vs remote connections

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

In the gRPC Java implementation, are objects serialized when sent from a gRPC service with a local connection in the same process?

Suppose we have one java process with two classes A and B. If class A uses a gRPC client to send data to a gRPC server backed by class B, do the client and server share a Java object reference, or is the data serialized and sent over the established local Netty connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the in-process transport, Protobuf serialization/deserialization will generally be avoided.

The Protobuf marshaller in gRPC generates an `InputStream` when serializing a message. When using the in-process transport, that `InputStream` is passed *back* to the Protobuf marshaller to deserialize a message. The Protobuf marshaller implements the `InputStream` directly and only serializes the message when bytes are actually read from the stream. When deserializing, [the marshaller checks whether it generated the `InputStream` and, if so, grabs the message directly and returns it](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/79e75bace40cea7e4be72e7dcd1f41c3ad6ee857/protobuf-lite/src/main/java/io/grpc/protobuf/lite/ProtoLiteUtils.java#L153) without ever converting the message to bytes. This is safe because Protobuf objects in Java are immutable.

This approach is unique to grpc-java with the in-process transport. Most other implementations *require* serializing to bytes and use mutable protocol buffers. grpc-netty encodes to HTTP/2, so always serializes to bytes.